# Determining correlation between discrete data

Tags: statistical-significance, categorical-data

I have two variables

1. The number of likes that a comment has received.
2. Total AFINN score calculated from a comment.

Now the AFINN algorithm assigns an integer based on the sentiment of each word (between -5 and 5+). The total AFINN score is the sum of all the AFINN scores in that comment.

I am trying to determine if these correlate. However, I have some issues.

1. The comment length is variable, and so the AFINN score is between -12 and 44+. Is there a way to determine the correlation between these variables?
2. If I split the AFINN scores into top and bottom, would this be a valid way to run statistical significance testing? If so, what would you run?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate correlations between these variables. The fact that one can be negative or positive is not a problem. The fact that number of likes is a count may be a limitation. Pearson correlation is checking how close the relationship is to linear. My wild guess is that a straight line relationship is unlikely here, but that doesn't make Pearson correlation totally useless. Spearman and Kendall correlations are checking how close the relationship is to monotonic.

The deeper question is why you are doing this any way. If it's an exploratory check on whether there is a relationship, then OK, but a graph might well be as or more helpful. At another wild guess, many comments attract none or a very few likes and a few comments might attract very many likes, and that's what it is, but it can be quite to hard to model such a situation with very simple tools.

As for splitting on AFINN scores, that sounds like a step backwards. I know nothing about AFINN scores, but they sound like an attempt to measure something systematically, and degrading measurements into arbitrary groups rarely helps in statistics, any more than splitting off tall and short people is any kind of advance on using people's heights as a predictor. What significance tests did you have in mind?

Comment: Thank you so much. I think I was over thinking the problem. You are completely right - The splitting of the data is arbitrary